# Why are not all of my slideUps working?

Tags: c#, jquery, html-select, slideup

I have this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id$=_AddressRows]').slideUp();
    $('[id$=panelSection2]').slideUp();
    $('[id$=panelSection3]').slideUp();
    $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').slideUp();
    $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').slideUp();
});
```

...which, for the most part, do their job, and hide the elements they are supposed to.

However, the two most recently added, the last two (for the dropdownlists) are not working.

I'm creating the elements in C# like so:

```
// add the comboboxes
DropDownList ddlPaymentToIndividual = new DropDownList();
ddlPaymentToIndividual.ID = "ddlPayToIndividual";
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Select type", "0"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Damage Payment", "1"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Fellowship / Scholarship", "2"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Funded Activity", "3"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Gift (Non-cash)", "4"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Honorarium", "5"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Online Training & Development", "6"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Participant Support", "7"));
ddlPaymentToIndividual.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Prize / Award (Non-cash)", "8"));
cellRadioButton1_2.Controls.Add(ddlPaymentToIndividual);

DropDownList ddlPaymentToVendor = new DropDownList();
ddlPaymentToVendor.ID = "ddlPayToVendor";
. . .
```

...but they display in spite of having been slid up. Why?

The pertinent rendered HTML is:

```
<td><select name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ddlPayToIndividual" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_ddlPayToIndividual">
                                <option value="0">Select type</option>
                                <option value="1">Damage Payment</option>
                                <option value="2">Fellowship / Scholarship</option>
                                <option value="3">Funded Activity</option>
                                <option value="4">Gift (Non-cash)</option>
                                <option value="5">Honorarium</option>
                                <option value="6">Online Training &amp; Development</option>
                                <option value="7">Participant Support</option>
                                <option value="8">Prize / Award (Non-cash)</option>

                            </select></td>
                            <td><select name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ddlPayToVendor" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_ddlPayToVendor">
                                <option value="0">Select type</option>
                                <option value="1">Donation / Contribution</option>
                                <option value="2">Membership</option>
                                <option value="3">Postage/Outbound Freight</option>
                                <option value="4">Refund to Research Agency</option>
                                <option value="5">Utilities</option>
                                <option value="6">Subscription</option>
                                <option value="7">Other/Miscellaneous</option>

                            </select></td>
```

Also, the jQuery code shown above is rendered verbatim.

NOTE: "hide" also does not work; I tried changing the code in the "ready" function to this:

```
$('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').hide();
$('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').hide();
```

...but it makes no diff.

### UPDATE

It turns out that this code:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=rbPaymentToIndividual]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').slideUp();
        $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').slideDown();
    }
});

$(document).on("click", '[id$=rbPaymentToVendor]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').slideUp();
        $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').slideDown();
    }
});
```

...*is* working (selecting a radio button does slide one up, and the other down). So it's not a problem with slideUp() per se. Is it a "timing" issue - when the slideUp()s are called in the ready function, the dropdownlists have not yet been created, and thus the calls are ignored? If that's the case, why do the *other* slideUp()s there work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "they" say, "timing is everything." This sort of code has to go, not in the "ready" function, but rather in the window load function, like so:

```
/* NOTE: Things that need to take place after all the elements have been constructed need to go here; the ready function can be too early */
$(window).load(function () {
    $('[id$=_AddressRows]').slideUp();
    $('[id$=panelSection2]').slideUp();
    $('[id$=panelSection3]').slideUp();
    $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').hide();
    $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').hide();
});
```